# About GCP Console login audit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, audit, google-stackdriver

I wonder How to get "audit log" GCP Console (https://console.cloud.google.com) loggin failure ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Audit Logging helps to determine who did what, where and when on Google Cloud Platform (GCP). You can find more information on this link [[1](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/)]. Stackdriver Logging [[2](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/)] also allows users to store, search, analyse, monitor, and alert on log data and events from Google Cloud Platform and Amazon Web Services (AWS).

Comment: I'm searching for the answer for the almost same question on this thread, but the accepted answer seems wrong. I can't find the audit log for the GCP Console login action. Can you guide me specifically where to find the audit logs for the login action? thanks in advance.